# $\dot{x}(t)=3x(t)^\frac{2}{3}$ ; $t\geq0$ ; $x(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I say id this differential equation have solution and if its unique:

$\dot{x}(t)=3x(t)^\frac{2}{3}$ ; $t\geq0$ ; $x(0)=0$

I stuck in this problem some help please.

Comment: [Picard-Lindelöf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)

Comment: ????????????????

Comment: Have you clicked the link and *read* what Wikipedia says? The article explains it quite well...

Comment: yes i have not seen this therem

Comment: Read the article! It has examples *very* similar to yours! You'll find that your ODE has a solution, but (as far as I can see) not a unique one - your right-hand side is *not* lipschitz continuous, because $x^\frac{2}{3}$ has an unbounded derivative around $0$. Thus, if you start at any $t_0 > 0$, the solution is unique, but if you start at $t_0 = 0$, not necessarily so. One solution is obviously $x(t) = 0$, so I suggest you try to find another one.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x,t)=x^{2/3}$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$, then using Peano's theorem, this Cauchy problem has solutions. In fact, it has infinitely many solutions, namely,
for $c\geq0$ the function $\psi_c:[0,+\infty)\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ defined by
$$
\psi_c(t)=\left\{\matrix{0&\hbox{if}& 0\leq t\leq c,\cr
(t-c)^3&\hbox{if}&c<t\phantom{\leq c}.}\right.
$$ 
is clearly a solution to the proposed Cauchy problem.

Answer (score 1):

The equation will have a unique solution if we take $f$ as the right hand side of the ode, so here $f(x)=3x^{\frac {2}{3}}$

if $ f$ is Lipschitz continuous on a domain including $0$, then your ode will have a unique solution there.

Is it Lipschitz?

Answer (score -3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
No need to read anything...
\begin{align}
\int_{{\rm x}\pars{0}}^{{\rm x}\pars{t}}{\dd\xi \over 3\xi^{2/3}} = \int_{0}^{t}\dd\tau
\quad\imp\quad{\rm x}^{1/3}\pars{t} - {\rm x}^{1/3}\pars{0} = t - 0
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#00f}{\large{\rm x}\pars{t} = t^{3}}
> $$

Comment: Problem is though, x(t)=0 is a solution, thats why I posted the lipschitz problem, since the solution is not unique.